# Decrypting SOAP Wcf-Webservice manually

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, soap

We are working on a webservice where the request from the client has to be encrypted and signed using X509 security. The issue is that we are not allowed to decrypt the message using the standard wcf-functionality, we need to decrypt the message manually since we are not allowed to decrypt the message in the security-zone where the service is going to be installed.

We are forwarding  the request using MSMQ (hopefully WCF Msmq-functionality).

Have tried different approaches, but hasn't found any good solution for this yet. At the moment I have created a simple aspx webpage for the entrypoint and we are forwarding the message into msmq.The MSmq WCF is in a zone where we are allowed to decrypt the message.

Aspx webpages is not a good solution, I guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A couple of points on your post. First, your description isn't completely clear. Do client requests arrive at your component signed and encrypted? If your component's security zone is insecure, decrypting messages "manually" would breach security, would it not?  It's helpful to be as specific as you can.  Second: you should ask specific questions.

Comment: If your encryption is configured correctly, your secure zone holds the *private* encryption key, and the client holds the public key. It is the other way around for the signature. Ordinarily encryption with PKI requires one key-pair, and signing requires another.  You may be able to verify the signature on the request in your insecure zone, but you won't be able to decrypt the message unless you somehow "steal" the private key. Don't do that; it will subvert the security zones you use.

Comment: Will try to create a better description next week. Thanks for the answer so far.